# Setting the size of title in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have the following script to place in a bash script:

```
    #!/bin/bash
    set -e
gnuplot -persist <<-EOFMarker
    set pixmap 1 "pathToimage/fig.png" at screen 0.85, 0 width screen 0.15 behind
    set rmargin at screen 0.85

    # Border line definition
    set border lw 1

    # Major and Minor grid definition
    set style line 100 lt 1 lc rgb "gray" lw 2
    set style line 101 lt 0.5 lc rgb "gray" lw 1
    set grid mytics ytics ls 100, ls 101
    set grid mxtics xtics ls 100, ls 101

    set title 'myTitle' font ", 30"
    set ylabel 'y [m]' font "Helvetica, 12"
    set xlabel 'x [m]' font "Helvetica, 12"
    set tics font "Helvetica,10"


    plot [-10:10] sin(x),atan(x),cos(atan(x))
EOFMarker
```

The script is intended to do some plotting and place a logo on the corner of the plot. However, I am not able to change the size of the fonts... I am using gnuplot 5.4.3.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to set a terminal? Maybe your default terminal does not support changing the title size.

Using this script, I can set the title size:

```
set pixmap 1 "linux.png" at screen 0.85, 0 width screen 0.15 behind
set rmargin at screen 0.85

# Border line definition
set border lw 1

# Major and Minor grid definition
set style line 100 lt 1 lc rgb "gray" lw 2
set style line 101 lt 0.5 lc rgb "gray" lw 1
set grid mytics ytics ls 100, ls 101
set grid mxtics xtics ls 100, ls 101

set term png  # new
set o "output.png"  # new
set title 'myTitle' font ", 30"
set ylabel 'y [m]' font ", 12"  # removed font spec
set xlabel 'x [m]' font ", 12"  # removed font spec
set tics font ",10"
plot [-10:10] sin(x),atan(x),cos(atan(x))
set o
```

The output is

[image: Large title]

If I set the font size to 12, I get
[image: normal title]

Comment: When settting to pngcairo I get: `line 0: unknown or ambiguous terminal type; type just 'set terminal' for a list`

Comment: Availables are: canvas, cgm, context, domterm, dumb, dxf, emf, epslatex, fig, gif, hpgl, jpeg, mf, mp, pcl5, pict2e, png, postscript, pslatex ,pstex, pstricks, svg , tek40xx, tek410x, texdraw, tkcanvas, unknown, vttek, x11, xlib

Comment: I had to install `sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libpango1.0-dev` and install again gnuplot as: `./configure`, `make` and `sudo make install`. However the cairo terminal does not give me the image in a terminal but in the output image

Comment: Should work with terminal `png` too. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Are there any interactive terminal's that can also do that? X11 does not appear to work

Comment: At least wxt and qt support them, but they are not listed on your side. Can you get them?

Comment: Ok. I get what I was missing: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1312764/how-to-install-gnuplot-5-4-at-ubuntu20-04. , Install the qt packages `sudo apt install qtbase5-dev qtbase5-dev-tools libqt5svg5-dev qttools5-dev-tools` and afterwards configure with Qt: `./configure --with-qt=qt5`. Now everything is working as expected

Comment: Consider [upvoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-can-i-upvote-answers-and-comments) the answer if it helped you, or [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), if it answered your question.